# Smoothness in cyclotomic versus complex fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Say we have a polynomial in a cyclotomic field; in particular, an n-th cyclotomic field, where n is the order of the polynomial's symmetry group. If we know the polynomial is smooth over this field, can we extrapolate that the polynomial is smooth over $\mathbb{C}$? Is there any existing theorem that states some variation of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth"?

Comment: The typical analytic definition- infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Then your question does not make sense, as all polynomials are infinitely differentiable over $\mathbb C$... (Well, it does make sense but the answer is trivially *yes*) Moreover, being "smooth over a cyclotomic field" then does not make much sense, nor is there any relationship between the group of a polynomial and anything else!)

Comment: Hmm maybe then I'm thinking of the wrong definition of smooth. If we define it as an algebraic variety without a singular point, does that answer still hold?

Comment: I have no idea what «If we define it as an algebraic variety without a singular point» means... If we define *what* in what way?

Comment: A smooth polynomial, that is, as an algebraic variety without a singular point. Apologies for pronoun vagueness.

Comment: A smooth polynomial is not an algebraic variety, and cannot be — at most, you might be referring to the zero set of a polynomial. It is very difficult to help you if we are not able to understand what you are asking!